# Replace live() with on() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a grider.js API which helps to create a table view where I can addRow and deleteRow from the table. For this there are two methods `addRow` and `deleteRow` are used. Both these methods use .live() to perform `click` action. So, as now after 1.7 version jQuery doesn't support .live(), I replaced them with .on() as shown in the following screenshot? I am not getting any error in the console but click action is not working. Can you sugesst what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Grider API used is from the following Github URL

[Grider](https://github.com/boriscy/grider)

Comment: Read the `$.fn.on()` doc for delegating event, you have to bind event to any static container and pass a selector string as parameter or read: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  BTW, using a plugin 9 years old doesn't sound like a great idea

Comment: yes thatswhy, I changed grider.js file on my server and changed .live() to .on() but its not working.

Comment: I just tell you to read the DOC, which you obviously didn't have done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace`live()` with `on()` using following syntax.

```
$(table).on('click', 'a.delete', function() {});
```

I'm assuming `table` is already present in DOM while you add this event.

Comment: Thanks this works, can you also suggest for 2nd one, should I add `"tr:not(.noedit):last a.delete"` or just `a.delete`?

Comment: I guess, you have apply full selector like you were doing with `live()`